# Does Ruby have a version of `python -i`?

Tags: python, ruby, command-line-arguments

I've been looking for a while, but I haven't found anything in Ruby like `python`'s `-i` flag.

Common behaviour for me if I'm testing something is to run the unfinished `python` script with a `-i` flag so that I can see and play around with the values in each variable.

If I try `irb <file>`, it still terminates at `EOF`, and, obviously `ruby <file>` doesn't work either. Is there a command-line flag that I'm missing, or some other way this functionality can be achieved?

**Edit:** Added an explanation of what kind of functionality I'm talking about.

#### Current Behaviour in Python

*file.py*

```
a = 1
```

*Command Prompt*

```
$ python -i file.py
>>> a
1
```

As you can see, the value of the variable `a` is available in the console too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a command-line flag that I'm missing, or some other way this functionality can be achieved?

Yes, there are both. I'll cover an "other way".

Starting with ruby 2.5, you can put a `binding.irb` in some place of your code and then the program will go into an interactive console at that point.

```
% cat stop.rb
puts 'hello'

binding.irb
```

Then

```
% ruby stop.rb
hello

From: stop.rb @ line 3 :

    1: puts 'hello'
    2:
 => 3: binding.irb
irb(main):001:0>
```

It was possible for a long time before, with `pry`. But now it's in the standard package.

Comment: For Ruby 2.4, I'm using `require 'irb'` and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `irb -r ./filename.rb` (`-r` for "require"), which should basically do the same as `python -i ./filename.py`.

**Edit** to better answer the refined question:

Actually, `irb -r ./filename.rb` does the equivalent of running `irb` and subsequently running 
`irb(main):001:0> require './filename.rb'`. Thus, local variables from `filename.rb` do not end up in scope for inspection.

`python -i ./filename.py` seems to do the equivalent of adding `binding.irb` to the last line of the file and then running it with `ruby ./filename.rb`. There seems to be no one-liner equivalent to achieve this exact behaviour for ruby.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give me access to the variables within `filename.rb`. Please see the edited question

Comment: @shashwat: local variables - no. But all other variables should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command irb. When that has started you can load and execute any ruby file with `load './filename.rb'`

Comment: yes, or you could use `irb -r ./filename.rb` directly, to more closely mimic python's command-line behaviour.

Comment: That sounds even better. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @Hendrik: indeed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give me access to the variables within `filename.rb`. Please see the edited question for an example